# I want to fetch data from three tables every table is linked with id's

Tags: php, mysql

```
I have three tables name product, brand, product_info

    **product table**
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `flag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;





  INSERT INTO `product` (`p_id`, `product`, `flag`) VALUES
    (1, 'Atta', 0),
    (2, 'Oil', 0),
    (3, 'Biscut', 0),
    (4, 'Rice', 0);

    Brand table
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brand` (
  `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;



INSERT INTO `brand` (`b_id`, `p_id`, `brand`, `image`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Ashirvad', 'FreeVector-Blue-Squares-Vector.jpg'),
(2, 1, 'Phillsberry', 'ILBAGNOALESSI_One_02.jpg'),
(3, 2, 'Sunflower', '001-bi-fold-corporate-brochure-template-vol-1-2.jpg'),
(4, 3, 'Good Day', 'but-ok-bg.gif'),
(5, 3, 'Sunfeast', 'but_call_bg.gif'),
(6, 4, 'Mosura', '2.jpg'),
(7, 4, 'Samba', '3.jpg');

    **Product_info table**

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_info` (
  `pi_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `measurement` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mrp` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `our_price` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pi_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;



INSERT INTO `product_info` (`pi_id`, `pro`, `b_id`, `quantity`, `measurement`, `mrp`, `our_price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '1', '1kg', '50', '48'),
(2, 1, 2, '1', '1kg', '60', '59'),
(3, 2, 3, '1', '1ltr', '90', '86'),
(4, 1, 1, '500', '500gms', '25', '23'),
(5, 2, 3, '500', '500ml', '45', '43'),
(6, 3, 4, '1', 'pcs', '15', '14'),
(7, 3, 5, '1', 'pcs', '10', '9'),
(8, 4, 6, '', '1 kg', '45', '43'),
(9, 4, 6, '', '500 gm', '23', '21'),
(10, 4, 7, '', '1 kg', '48', '47'),
(11, 4, 7, '', '500 gm', '24', '23');

         I used the below code to list the items from product table according to p_id

    $result = mysql_query("select * FROM product"); 
                    echo '<ul class="list-1 p2">'; 
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                        // Print out the contents of each row into a table

                        echo '<li>';
                        echo "<a href='page.1.php?pid=$row[p_id]'>";
                        echo '<b>';
                        echo $row['product'];
                        echo '</b>';
                        echo "</a>";
                        echo '</li>';
                    } 
                    echo '</ul>';
                    mysql_close($con);


     **My intention is to display as in the below code**

     mysql_select_db("mr_bazaar",$con);
                    $pid=$_GET['pid'];
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT p.product,b.brand,pi.quantity,pi.mrp,pi.our_price,pi.measurement FROM product as p INNER JOIN brand as b ON p.p_id=b.p_id
INNER JOIN product_info as pi ON pi.b_id=b.b_id WHERE p.p_id=$pid"); 
                    echo '<ul class="list-1 p2">'; 
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                        // Print out the contents of each row into a table

                       echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>';
                        echo $row['brand'];
                        echo '</td><td>';
                        echo '<select name= qty>';
                        echo '<option value= 1>1</option>
                              <option value= 2>2</option>
                              <option value= 3>3</option>
                              <option value= 4>4</option>
                              <option value= 5>5</option>
                              <option value= 6>6</option>
                              <option value= 7>7</option>
                              <option value= 8>8</option>
                              <option value= 9>9</option>
                              <option value= 10>10</option>';
                        echo '</select>';

                        echo '</td><td>';   
                        echo $row['mrp'];
                        echo '</td><td>';
                        echo $row['our_price'];                     
                        echo '</td><td>';               
                        echo "<select name='measurement'>";
                                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                    $id = $row['p_id'];
                                                    $measurement = $row['measurement'];
                                                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row['p_id'] . "\">" . $row['measurement'] . "</option>";
                                                }
                                                echo "</select>";

                        echo '</td><td>';




                        echo '</td>';
                    } 
                    echo '</ul>';
                    mysql_close($con);
```

But I want to display the list such as brand Qty Price  Our Price   Measurement(value in the dropdown list as per the table). When I use the above code it displays only one item! As per the image it is displaying only Ashirvad, but in the table Phillsberry also there 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first while loop will always end up with only one iteration because you have a inner while loop which is also iterating with the same variable that's being used in the first while loop.

So in the case you  given in the example its returning 3 records, so your first while loop iterate it by one which shows 1 record and the inner while loop iterate 2 more time showing the measurements.

So in this case the very straight forward solution would be not to use same variable for iteration in the inner while loop and do a separate query to get all the measurement for that brand. Please check the below code, I made some corrections just to show different produts/brands listing. You can change the logic based on your product display requirement.

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT p.product,b.brand,pi.quantity,pi.mrp,pi.our_price,group_concat(pi.measurement) as measurement
                    FROM product as p 
                    INNER JOIN brand as b ON p.p_id=b.p_id
                    INNER JOIN product_info as pi ON pi.b_id=b.b_id 
                    WHERE p.p_id=$pid 
                    GROUP BY b.b_id");

echo '<ul class="list-1 p2">';
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) { // if result found
    echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        // Print out the contents of each row into a table

       echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row['brand'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo '<select name= qty>';
        echo '<option value= 1>1</option>
              <option value= 2>2</option>
              <option value= 3>3</option>
              <option value= 4>4</option>
              <option value= 5>5</option>
              <option value= 6>6</option>
              <option value= 7>7</option>
              <option value= 8>8</option>
              <option value= 9>9</option>
              <option value= 10>10</option>';
        echo '</select>';

        echo '</td><td>';   
        echo $row['mrp'];
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo $row['our_price'];                     
        echo '</td><td>';

        $measurement = explode(',', $row['measurement']); // to get different measurements for a brand 

        echo "<select name='measurement'>";
        foreach ($measurement as $measure) {
            echo $measure."<br/>";

            echo "<option value=\"" . $row['p_id'] . "\">" . $measure . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

        echo '</td><td>';

        echo '</tr>';
    } 
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "No result found";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: When i select the measurement value its associated price has to change in mrp and our_price from the table and while selecting the "qty" it has multiply with our_price value

Comment: You try the same way I did for measurement and show the mrp and our_price in drop down and change you price based on changes made to measurement drop down. If you find difficulties this way you can you do 2 different queries one for selecting you product and one for getting your mrp.our_price and measurement for each of your product.Let me know if you need more assistant. And FYI:I just edited the top post, now it will show you product listing.

Comment: I dont want the mrp and our_price in dropdown.

Comment: I dont want the mrp and our_price in dropdown. When I select the measurement value (like  1kg in Ashirvad it's mrp and our_price has change to 50 and 48 respectively  )

Comment: Yes, I understood what you are trying to do and that what I explained in my last comment how you can get get mrp and our_price like you are getting measurement. Please give me some time I will edit my post to get mrp and our_price as well

Comment: Then you need to do a ajax call to get the corresponding mrp and our_price for that measurement selected OR you can use HTML storage to store the corresponding mrp and our_price for each measurement.

Comment: If u don't mind plz code me this?

Comment: OK, I will do it for you and post in a separate POST, Pls give me some time.

Comment: I have the working script ready with me, but not able to post as answer section is closed for this. Let me know if you want it in any other mean.

Comment: plz mail me to vijey.sw@gmail.com